# Proof explanation: $|X|=|Y|=m \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists exactly $m! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

**Lemma.** For sets $A, B$ with $|X|=|Y|=m \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists exactly $m! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot m$ pairwise distinct bijective maps between $X$ and $Y$.

*Proof is left as an exercise.*

---

Looks like the proof has to do with combinatorics but don't know how to make a fist assumption/claim.

Things we can conclude:

1. We have $n$ elements from which we want to know the number of ways to choose $k$ elements, thus the size of both our sets $X$ and $Y$ is $\binom{n}{k}$.
2. Symmetry Rule for the Binomial Coefficient states that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$. Therefore, we could say that $|X| = \binom{n}{k}$ and $|Y| = \binom{n}{n-k}$

I do not know if that is even useful and, if so, where to go from there.

---

Liesen, J., Mehrmann, V. 2015. Linear Algebra. Berlin, Germany.: Springer.

Comment: You need to choose $f(1),...,f(m)$ without repetition. There are $m$ ways of choosing $f(1)$, there are $m-1$ ways of choosing $f(2)$, etc,etc, so there are $m \cdot (m-1) \cdots 1 = m!$ ways of choosing $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Prove it by induction on $m$. Note that it suffices to assume that $X=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$. (Why?) The case $m=1$ is trivial. At the induction step consider the number of choices for $f(m+1)$ and then the number of possibilities for $f\upharpoonright\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: **My attempt:** _(1)_ Let $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{a,b\}$. The arrangements in which we can pair the elements of $X$ and $Y$ are the following: $(1a, 2b)$ and $(1b, 2a)$. _(2)_ Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Y=\{a,b,c\}$, the arrangements are the following: $(1a, 2b, 3c)$, $(1a, 2c, 3b)$, $(1b, 2a, 3c)$, $(1b, 2c, 3a)$, $(1c, 2a, 3b)$ and $(1c, 2b, 3a)$. For _(1)_ there were $2!$ arrangements and for _(2)_ there were $3!$ arrangements. Thus, we can conclude that for $|X| = |Y| = m \in \mathbb{N}$ there will be $m!$ possible arrangements.

Comment: @RoSegura: I’m afraid not: you’ve merely verified that the assertion is true for the specific cases $m=2$ and $m=3$. That proves nothing about the cases with $m\ge 4$ and is not an induction argument. For an induction argument you would first verify the $m=1$ case. Then you would assume that it is true for some unspecified $m$ and somehow use that assumption to prove that it is true for $m+1$.

Answer (score 0):

A bijective mapping $f:A \rightarrow B$ can be thought as putting $m$ distinct fruits of $B$ in $m$ distinct buckets of $A$ each having exactly one fruit.

And we know that we can distribute $m$ fruits in $m$ buckets in $m!$ ways.